# Can you use VueJS transition-group functionality with pug template?

Tags: vue.js, pug, transition

Is it possible to use transition-group with pug templates?

```
.events-list
  transition-group(name="list")
    .event(v-for="(event, index) in showing" :key="event.id" :style="{'background-image': `url(${event.image.fields.file.url})`}")
```

Will something like this work? If so, how to create the transition effects?

Comment: You should try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does work.
I wasnt seeing it in action because unfortunately it doesnt work with "flex" displays, once I changed to display "block" or "inline-block" it started working again.